# Frayed duct vent - can it still be used?

Tags: hvac, ventilation, ducts

I removed an old noisy bathroom fan and the duct attached to it is just frayed. (If that's the word) I've tried cutting these ducts before and I just end up unraveling a bunch more than I should.
That's actually the situation I find myself in.
[image]

I really don't want to replace this duct tube, it looks like a pain to go to the 
flashing and route a new tube.
So the question is - can I still use this? and if so, how can I make the end of it acceptable for the out of the bathroom vent.
Note the duct and the vent are both 3".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not WANT to, but in some decades of dealing with that junk, my approach now when I come cross the junk is to replace it with solid metal pipe and solid metal joints, and be done with it. So that's what I'd strongly suggest doing, like it or not. it's low quality, reduces airflow, and is generally horrid.

As for re-using it, which I recommend against - wrap a strip of duct tape around it past any damage to make a nice straight guideline for cutting, and cut along it. Use a nice sharp set of aircraft snips. Cut, do not tear.

[image: Aircraft snips]

If then too short, add a coupling or use some solid vent pipe to make up the difference.